# JSON.NET - read-only properties & support for IgnoreDataMember

Tags: json.net

Does JSON.NET support the `IgnoreDataMember` attribute or do I have to use `JsonIgnore` instead? Is this something that will be support in future?

In addition I've found that JSON.NET is serializing properties that are get only - is this intended behaviour? Is it something we can switch off at serializer level?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question, but thought it may be helpful to others...

We ended up implementing this using a custom `IContractResolver`. We want the functionality of the `DefaultContractResolver` so we derive from that then tweak `CreateProperty` to ignore things we don't really care to serialise. E.g.

```
    internal class IgnoreDataMemberContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            JsonProperty property =  base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
            property.Ignored |= member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IgnoreDataMemberAttribute), true).Length > 0;
            return property;
        }
    }
```