# Custom IActionInvoker and async Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, task-parallel-library

I'm using NInject as the default container and the [NInjectResolver class](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/using-ninject-with-the-latest-asp-net-web-api-source/) on an MVC4 project. Injection works great.

Now I'm trying to replace the default `IActionInvoker` in order to provide custom JSON serialization as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878694/165656).

This seems to work OK if the action returns `JsonResult` but it chokes on `Task<JsonResult>` (even if I bind `IActionInvoker` to the default `ControllerActionInvoker`).

When I convert it to an async action, the action returns (instead of JSON), this text: `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult>` - like calling `ToString()` on it.

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are working with Task-based async, you'll have to look at injecting an instance of [`AsyncControllerActionInvoker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.async.asynccontrolleractioninvoker%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks - can you clarify however: will this also work for non-async actions? If not, should I bind one such invoke for IAsyncInvoker and a ControllerActionInvoker for IActionInvoker? In other words, how can I handle both cases with minimal effort/code?

Comment: You only need to register the async one, since starting with MVC 4 all controllers support async, but if you have sync methods those will work as usual. `Controller.CreateActionInvoker()` by default returns an `AsyncControllerActionInvoker`, which ultimately knows how to handle sync and async patterns (via [`AsyncActionMethodSelector.GetActionDescriptorDelegate()`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c97168711de8#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fAsync%2fAsyncActionMethodSelector.cs)).