# How to use Json.NET as default deserializer in an ASP.NET MVC 3+ application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, json.net

There're a lot of resources on how to substitute the Json.NET library as the [default **serializer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7150912/304588) in ASP.NET MVC apps, but, for the life of me, I can't find a single resource on how to set it as the default **deserializer**.

To illustrate that a bit, here's some template code:

```
                              // how to use Json.NET when deserializing
                              // incoming arguments?
                                    V
public ActionResult SomeAction ( Foo foo ) {

    // this piece of code has lots of resources
    // on how to override the default Javascript serializer
    return Json(new Bar());

}
```

How do I tell my application to use Json.NET when deserializing incoming parameters in controller actions, say, from a jQuery AJAX call?

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    data : { foo : 'bar' }
});
```

I've tried adapting `MediaTypeFormatters` into my code by adjusting [this resource from Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/09/Using-an-alternate-JSON-Serializer-in-ASPNET-Web-API), but that didn't work either. Note that I'm not in a WebAPI environment --- but I expect that one solution that works on a normal `Controller` should work (albeit with minimal adjustments) in an `ApiController`.

Comment: Did you fix this issue somehow?

Comment: @Jaap I remember having to drop this before, but I did try out Fatal's suggestion below and that worked to a great extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to implement a custom ValueProviderFactory and remove the standard JsonValueProviderFactory.

There's some example code here: http://json.codeplex.com/discussions/347099 however reading through the comments, i'm not 100% sure that it will properly handle dictionaries.

Comment: This article does not provide a way to customize Json conversion using JsonConverter attributes.