# Is it possible to control the JSON serialization behavior of JsonServiceClient?

Tags: .net, servicestack

I am trying to interact with an ASP.NET MVC controller action using a ServiceStack JsonServiceClient.  The default serialization behavior of DateTime objects does not seem to be compatible with what MVC supports, is there any way to alter client's DateTime serialization behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the ServiceStack DateTime serialization can be controlled by setting the `ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.DateHandler` property.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to alter client's DateTime serialization behavior?

In ASP.NET MVC there are 2 aspects: model binding JSON requests and sending JSON responses. Both use the built-in .NET `JavaScriptSerializer`.

In order to alter the model binder you could write a [`custom ValueProviderFactory`](https://gist.github.com/DalSoft/1588818).

For response JSON objects you could write a custom ActionResult instead of using the built-in Json method as shown in [`this thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7150912/29407).

If you want to alter the behavior on the client then you could use what @AlexD suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16569219/29407).