# Bind JSON to JToken in MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

Is there a way I can get an MVC controller to bind incoming dynamic JSON to a `JToken` object?

If I use an API Controller I can do this:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(JToken json)
    {
    }
}
```

and the posted json gets converted into a `JToken` object.
However if I use an MVC controller it results in a server error.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestAction(JToken json)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

I realise there other ways to obtain the incoming data but I would prefer to receive it as a JToken in the MVC Controller.

I have tried to use a custom `ValueProviderFactory` [from here](https://gist.github.com/rorymurphy/db0b02e8267960a0881a) but I still get a server error returned from my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Test/TestAction',    //or /api/Test
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({foo:"bar",wibble:"wobble"})
}).done(function (res) {
    alert('ok');
}).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert('error')
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Note - As stated above I have replaced the default `JsonValueProviderFactory` with one based on `Json.NET`.

On further investigation it appears that the problem occurs in the `DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel` method. When the `DefaultModelBinder` tries to create a `JToken` instance it fails because `JToken` is an abstract class. Even if I change the `TestAction` parameter to a `JObject` it stills fails, presumably because there are `JToken` properties further down the object heirarchy.

Comment: is your JToken class having foo and wibble properties?

Comment: @Karthik It is a [Json.NET JToken Class](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jtoken.htm)

Comment: ok. does that class includes foo and wibble properties?

Comment: ASP.Net MVC uses `JavaScriptSerializer` not Json.NET.  To switch, see [Setting the Default JSON Serializer in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591750) and [How to use Json.NET for JSON modelbinding in an MVC5 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995210).

Comment: @dbc Thanks, Jason Butera's answer in your second link provided the solution, I also needed to create a custom ModelBinder based on Json.NET. Do you want to provide an answer and I'll accept it or shall I show the solution?

Comment: @JonSusiak - Glad to help.  I'd recommend making your own answer.  Since you needed to extend the answer I found, it isn't an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, changing the default serializer for incoming JSON by [writing a custom `ValueProviderFactory`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995210/how-to-use-json-net-for-json-modelbinding-in-an-mvc5-project#24012035) did not work. This appears to be because `JToken` is an abstract class and the default ModelBinder can't create a model instance where abstract classes are involved.

The solution was to [create a custom `ModelBinder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995210/how-to-use-json-net-for-json-modelbinding-in-an-mvc5-project#34030497) for the Action:

```
public class JsonNetModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (!IsJSONRequest(controllerContext))
        {
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }

        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var jsonStringData = new StreamReader(request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStringData, bindingContext.ModelType);
    }
    private static bool IsJSONRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        var contentType = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
        return contentType.Contains("application/json");
    }
}
```

And use the custom `ModelBinder` on the Action as follows:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestAction([ModelBinder(typeof(JsonNetModelBinder))] JToken json)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```