# Passing json to mvc controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post some data via jQuery ajax to an Asp.Net MVC controller. I have the follow class which I am working with:

```
public class InnerStyle
{
   [JsonProperty("color")]
   public string HeaderColor { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("font-size")]
   public string HeaderFontSize { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("font-family")]
   public string HeaderFontFamily { get; set; }
}
```

The post method looks like:

```
public JsonResult UpdateRecord(InnerStyle innerStyle)
{
   //Do some validation 

   return Json("OK");
}
```

And my jQuery looks like:

```
$('#font-size-ddl').change(function () {
   var value = $(this).val();
   headerObj["font-size"] = value;
   console.log(JSON.stringify({ innerStyle: headerObj }));
   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "@Url.Action("UpdateRecord", "Document")",
          data: JSON.stringify({ innerStyle: headerObj}),
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          }
     });
});
```

The console.log in the above change event produces the following JSON string:

```
{"innerStyle":{"text-align":"","font-size":"20px","color":""}}
```

Now the issue I am having is if I set a break point on my `UpdateRecord` Action and see what is coming through the `innerStyle` object is null. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong please.

Comment: Seems like [JsonProperty] is from Newtonsoft.Json. Asp.net controller doesn't support it

Comment: @DanilEroshenko So what other option do I have to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: you can look at Model Binder.. In short the data should be available in Request itself.

Comment: If you want to use newtonsoft.json, you should probably look at MVC ModelBinder

Comment: Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995210/how-to-use-json-net-for-json-modelbinding-in-an-mvc5-project

Comment: You can simply change the controller signature to this: `public JsonResult UpdateRecord(string innerStyle)` and deserialize the string inside the method using Json.Net.

Comment: @Ardit It still does send anything back I have already tried that.

Comment: @DanilEroshenko I don't have to use newtonsoft,json if there is another way

Comment: @Code have you tried without the JSON.stringify but sending directly the object?

Comment: @Code even your propery doesn't match object c# with object javascript (font-family <-> text-align)

Comment: Try [DataMember(Name="somename")]

Comment: @DanilEroshenko That does not work either

Comment: @Ardit I have a property in my object I did not include it in the question

Comment: Try adding the propery to the Ajax call:  `datatype: 'json'` before the contentType using `data: JSON.stringify({ innerStyle: headerObj}),`

Comment: @Code then I bet it uses System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer that doesn't support DataMember properties (as DataContractJsonSerializer does). So you need to use ModelBinding anyway. You can try it with DataContractJsonSerializer instead of Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: You don't need to use the key while passing data to a controller `data: JSON.stringify(headerObj)` given `headerObj` is an object similar to your model `InnerStyke`

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the below code and it's working fine.

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "@Url.Action("UpdateRecord", "Document")",
          data: JSON.stringify({"text-align":"","font-size":"20px","color":""}),
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          }
     });
```

I simply removed the parameter name **"innerStyle"**. I just noticed one thing which might be a typo error. You are passing a property **"text-align":""** instead of **"font-family"**. So it's not populating all properties inside the controller's action **UpdateRecord(InnerStyle innerStyle)**. You should pass similar to the below json object to map the entire object on controller's action **UpdateRecord(InnerStyle innerStyle)**

```
{
  "color": "sample string 1",
  "font-size": "sample string 2",
  "font-family": "sample string 3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Code, your code is fine. It's just you cannot use [Json Property] while you are hitting controller via ajax. you have to use real class properties.

```
 $('#font-size-ddl').change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var headerObj = {};
    headerObj["HeaderColor"] = "Red";
    headerObj["HeaderFontSize"] = value;
    headerObj["HeaderFontFamily"] = "Arial";
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ custom: headerObj }));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("UpdateRecord", "Employee")",
        traditional: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({ custom: headerObj }),
        dataType: JSON,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```