# Change JSON serialization provider in ASP.NET MVC 5 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET MVC app that subscribes to webhook on launch, processes incoming JSONs and sends JSON-formatted responses. I find default serialization not suitable for my needs, because I need to tell the application which properties of my classes should be serialized and which names those properties are bound to (i.e. the property is `InputFile`, but JSON property must be `input_file`, etc.). I found that WCF's DataContracts are the easiest way to achieve this. The problem is that I am unsure if it is okay for my action to return `EmptyResult`  and send requests containing JSON in its body, so I am trying to replace the default serialization provider (which seems to be using `JavascriptSerializer` class).

Comment: Why do not you want to use https://www.newtonsoft.com/json There are attributes which allow to ignore properties to have names in the JSON file differ from the names in the model, ways to implement custom converters and many more things. Just take a look.

Comment: But even if I'd want to use Newtonsoft, doesn't the question still apply? I have no idea how to replace the default serialization provider used in `Json()` function.

Comment: Will it help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995210/how-to-use-json-net-for-json-modelbinding-in-an-mvc5-project

Comment: With my incompetence all that mass of code looks so terrible I'd rather just send `HttpRequest` myself and return `EmptyResult` from my action.