# ASP.NET 4.6 MVC How to return a Json result including datetime data with correct timezone?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.6

I wish to return a Json Result containing the datetime queried from database. The testing on my local machine is without any problem, however, after publishing to production server, all datetime show 3 hours ahead. I assume it is due to the server located in another timezone area.

Need help to solve this issue.

**Data in Database (MS SQL):**

```
StartDt: 2019-07-02 04:00:00.000
```

**Controller.cs:**

```cs
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetAll()
        {
            CalendarModel calendarModel = new CalendarModel();

            var calendarEvents = from cal in db.Calendar
                                 orderby cal.created descending
                                 select cal;


            return Json(calendarEvents, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**Json Result Fetched from my compuer:**

```
[
    {
        //some data
        "startDt": "/Date(1562054400000)/",
        //some data
    },
```

The above datetime is parsed as "2019-07-02T04:00:00.000-04:00", which is correct.

**Json Result Fetched from production server (queried from same database):**

```
[
    {
        //some data
        "startDt": "/Date(1562065200000)/",
        //some data
    },
```

This datetime is "2019-07-02T07:00:00.000-04:00", which is wrong.

**--------Update my solution-------**

Thank `@TommasoBertoni`'s answer inspired me that the key reason for this issue is due to the `Unspecified` DateTime Kind by default but turns to be `local` while Json serializing. So just need to set the DateTime Kind to `UTC` can solve that, but be aware that parsing the DateTime in front end also need to take it as `UTC` otherwise it will be considered as `local` by default.

**Controller.cs:**

```cs
 [HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetAll()
        {
            CalendarModel calendarModel = new CalendarModel();

            var calendarEvents = from cal in db.Calendar
                                 orderby cal.created descending
                                 select cal;
            //Add this
            foreach (var item in calendarEvents)
            {
                item.startDt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(item.startDt, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            }

            return Json(calendarEvents, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**.js**
(using `moment.js` library)

```js
//parse it as utc
  moment.utc(startDt).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Have you checked the timezone on production? This is a timezone mismatch

Comment: Which database is this, and how is it configured? What do you want the value in the database to mean, exactly?

Comment: How are you turning the `Date` into a date object and where are you getting your "date" (2019-07-02T07:00:00.000-04:00) from on the client side? That looks like a date representation for a UTC-4 timezone, so your assesment that `2019-07-02T04:00:00.000-04:00` *"is correct"* doesn't seem right

Comment: The dates are probably not saved as UTC.

Comment: @tech-y I can't do any configuration on database. So I think the only way is to do something on server.

Comment: @JonSkeet the datetime in the database is 4am. I want 4am. That's it. But on production server it returns 7am to me.

Comment: "I want 4am" - when returning a date/time in the JSON format you're using (the `/Date(...)/` there's no such thing as just 4am. It represents an *instant* in time. Which instant are you interested in? That instant in time might be 4am in some places and 7am in other places. Are you actually trying to represent an instant in time, or a "local" date/time that will mean different instants in time in different time zones?

Comment: @TommasoBertoni do you mean I should do something on the column of the datetime?

Comment: (And again, what database server is this, and how is it configured? Even though you can't *change* the configuration, it's still important to understand it.)

Comment: @JonSkeet It's MS SQL. The data type is datetime and allow null.

Comment: @Lei.L can you check the `Kind` of the dates fetched from the database? (`date.Kind`) it can be either `Unspecified`, `Local` or `Utc`. This should help us understand if the conversion occurs during the fetch of the values or during the json serialization.

Comment: Okay, it would be worth including that information in the question. Now what *exactly* are you intending to represent in the database? Is it meant to be an instant in time, or a floating "2019-07-02 04:00:00.000 wherever I happen to be"? Those are quite different kinds of value.

Comment: @TommasoBertoni It is `Unspecified`

Comment: Therefore it may be the json serialization that assumes the date is in local time, since it's _not_ universal

Comment: @TommasoBertoni I agree with your opinion, the same as what I researched before I think. But I got lost while trying. Could you please write down your answer below?

Comment: @Lei.L is the json result that you showed us returned directly from the api, or was it first received & parsed by a javascript frontend?

Comment: @TommasoBertoni Fetched from api directly via `Postman`

Comment: @Lei.L are you using the default json serializer? is there a custom configuration on startup?

Comment: @TommasoBertoni It's default. I didn't do anything on json serializer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that ASP.NET uses a [custom Microsoft JSON date format](https://davidsekar.com/javascript/converting-json-date-string-date-to-date-object), that encodes DateTime values as `/Date(ticks)/`, where ticks represents milliseconds since epoch (UTC).
So November 29, 1989, 4:55:30 AM, in UTC is encoded as `/Date(628318530718)/` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format) for more).

Example:

- Microsoft JSON date format: `/Date(1563464520158)/`
- ISO 8601 format: `2019-07-18T15:42:02.4592008Z`

If a DateTime has an `Unspecified` kind, it will be assumed as `Local` and the value will be conveted to UTC in order to get the ticks since epoch.

This json format is *still used in MVC, but not in Web API*: this means that when you are in a `Controller` and serialize the result with `Json(...)` you'll get the non-ISO format, but if you're in an `ApiController` the default serializer is Json.NET, which supports the ISO 8601 format and won't convert the DateTime value.

So, to fix this behavior **either you switch to Web APIs, or if you want to keep using the MVC controller, you can see the answers to these questions:**

- [Setting the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591750/setting-the-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc)
- [Using JSON.NET as the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109967/using-json-net-as-the-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc-3-is-it-possible)
- [How to use Json.NET for JSON modelbinding in an MVC5 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995210/how-to-use-json-net-for-json-modelbinding-in-an-mvc5-project)

*...or you could force the DateTime Kind to be Utc right before the json serialization, but I wouldn't recommend that.*

---

```cs
class TestRepo
{
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;

        // Use DateTime instances with different Kind
        // showing that it doesn't impact the serialization format.
        var utc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(now.Ticks), DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var local = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(now.Ticks), DateTimeKind.Local);
        var unspecified = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(now.Ticks), DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

        return new DateTime[] { utc, local, unspecified };
    }
}
```

```cs
// MVC controller
public class MVCValuesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<DateTime> dates = new TestRepo().GetDates();
        return Json(dates, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

// json result:
[
    "/Date(1563465361835)/", // <-- Utc
    "/Date(1563458161835)/", // <-- Local
    "/Date(1563458161835)/"  // <-- Unspecified
]
```

```cs
// Web API controller
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> Get()
    {
        IEnumerable<DateTime> dates = new TestRepo().GetDates();
        return dates;
    }
}

// json result:
[
    "2019-07-18T15:56:03.6401158Z",      // <-- Utc
    "2019-07-18T15:56:03.6401158+02:00", // <-- Local
    "2019-07-18T15:56:03.6401158"        // <-- Unspecified
]
```

Comment: Appreciate your perfect explanation inspiring me solved my problem!