# Cannot set a custom contract resolver in web api configuration

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

How can I set a custom contract resolver in web api configuration?  My code is relatively new and has no custom contract resolver till now.

I have added no other customization besides routing.

I tried in three different ways and none worked:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{            
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    //attempt 1
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver();

    //attempt 2
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver();

    //attempt 3
    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver()
    };           
}
```

The custom contract resolver code, breakpoint never reaches here when I'm debugging:

```
public class CustomContractResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"([_])(\w)");

        if (regex.IsMatch(propertyName))
        {
            var result = regex.Replace(propertyName.ToLower(), (match) => { return match.Groups[2].Value.ToUpper(); });
            return result;
        }
        else
            return base.ResolvePropertyName(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Is there something that is missing?

**Edit 1:**

I'm using ASP.NET WebApi 5.2.1 AND MVC 5.2.7, JSON.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) v13.0.1 (and already tried the old v12)

My Global Asax is very simple as well:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); //<- web api configuration
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); //<- mvc configuration
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

The MVC RouteConfig class:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

Here is some test web api controllers:

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Kronos.Web.Geolocalizacao.Controllers.Api
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public TestModel Obtain()
        {
            return new TestModel { CODE_IDENTIFICATION = 1, DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION = "TEST DAT THING" };
        }
    }

    public class TestModel
    {
        public decimal CODE_IDENTIFICATION { get; set; }

        public string DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Used the Tabbed Postman chrome addon to test

[Postman tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzVtU.png)

Comment: Is your issue with [tag:asp.net-web-api] or [tag:asp.net-mvc-5]?  They use different serializers, and the serializer used changes with the version, so might you please [edit] your question to be specific as to exactly which version and setup you are using?

Comment: If MVC, be aware that [tag:asp.net-mvc-5] is pretty old, the first version was released in 2013.  It doesn't use Json.NET by default.  If you want to use Json.NET for serialization in MVC5, see [Setting the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14591750/3744182/). If you want to use it for model binding, look at [How to use Json.NET for JSON modelbinding in an MVC5 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23995210/3744182/).

Comment: i'm using both, asp net mvc 5 and asp net web api, .net framework 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with how you are registering your global settings -- setting `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver` is correct as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28552567/3744182).  Your problem is that Json.NET **does not call [`ResolvePropertyName()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_ResolvePropertyName.htm) when the contract resolver also has a [`NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_NamingStrategy.htm)** -- and your base class `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` does indeed have a naming strategy.

This can be verified by checking the current Json.NET [reference source for `DefaultContractResolver.SetPropertySettingsFromAttributes()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/f7e7bd05d9280f17993500085202ff4ea150564a/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L1524):

> ```
> if (namingStrategy != null)
> {
>     property.PropertyName = namingStrategy.GetPropertyName(mappedName, hasSpecifiedName);
> }
> else
> {
>     property.PropertyName = ResolvePropertyName(mappedName);
> }
> ```

Broken demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/how1RS).

If I simply modify your `CustomContractResolver` to inherit from `DefaultContractResolver` (which has a null `NamingStrategy` by default), then it works:

```
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly NamingStrategy baseNamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy();

    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"([_])(\w)");

        if (regex.IsMatch(propertyName))
        {
            var result = regex.Replace(propertyName.ToLower(), (match) => { return match.Groups[2].Value.ToUpper(); });
            return result;
        }
        else
            return baseNamingStrategy.GetPropertyName(propertyName, false);
    }
}
```

Fixed demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zhhl4c).

However, a cleaner solution would be to replace your custom contract resolver with a custom naming strategy:

```
public class CustomNamingStrategy : CamelCaseNamingStrategy
{
    public CustomNamingStrategy() : base() { }
    public CustomNamingStrategy(bool processDictionaryKeys, bool overrideSpecifiedNames) : base(processDictionaryKeys, overrideSpecifiedNames) { }
    public CustomNamingStrategy(bool processDictionaryKeys, bool overrideSpecifiedNames, bool processExtensionDataNames) : base(processDictionaryKeys, overrideSpecifiedNames, processExtensionDataNames) { }

    readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"([_])(\w)");
    protected  override string ResolvePropertyName(string name)
    {
        if (regex.IsMatch(name))
        {
            var result = regex.Replace(name.ToLower(), (match) => { return match.Groups[2].Value.ToUpper(); });
            return result;
        }
        return base.ResolvePropertyName(name);
    }
}
```

And then configure it in settings like so:

```
settings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
    // Set the constructor parameters as per your preference.  These values are consistent with CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
    NamingStrategy = new CustomNamingStrategy(processDictionaryKeys: true, overrideSpecifiedNames: true),
};
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZwfsC2).