# Difference between JavaScriptSerializer and Controller Method Json

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

What Is the difference between `JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Object data);` and `Json(Object data);`. Should I be worried in picking one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Json()` method in the MVC `Controller` class creates a `JsonResult`, which  uses the `JavaScriptSerializer` class behind the scenes.  You can see this in the [source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/JsonResult.cs).   So there is really no difference between the two methods, except that it is a bit more code if you choose to use the `JavaScriptSerializer` manually.

To alleviate any confusion, I would point out that the built-in `JavaScriptSerializer` class is not part of [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), which is a third-party open source library mentioned by @Rahul.  It is possible to use this library with ASP.NET MVC if you want, but you may need to add a small amount of infrastructure to support it.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7109967/10263) for details on how to do that.  But unless you're working with huge amounts of data or have special serialization needs that aren't supported by the `JavaScriptSerializer`, there is usually no need to switch.