# EF 4.3 Json.Net 6.0.8 not taking programatic params in serialization

Tags: json.net

I'm using json.net for first time. It's really simple, but I have a problem: It seems to be JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, Formatting.Indented) should return no references and by using PreserveReferencesHandling = Ignore, it should dispose $id attributes as well, but I can't manage it.

My JsonConvert.SerializeObject call is in a razor view (MVC3) and JSON string I'm getting is

```
  {"Items": [
    {
      "$id": \"1\",
      "ID_DB": 18,
      "ID_SAP": null,
      ...
    }]
}
```

Perhaps, I need to change Web.config or put more config settings in another file(s) in my project. Please, can you tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks you all in advance.

Regards

Tistklehoff

Comment: There is probably some default configuration code in your project's global.asax.cs file or thereabouts which is causing this as the default behavior will definitely not preserve $id like that. Look for a call to config.Formatters or something similar.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot, I'm getting some data as "DATA": { $ref:XX } also, so, It's time to have a look to config.Formatters...

Comment: My global.asax.cs is clear, because I'm using one-shot transforms, as here: (Option 1, single jsonconvert)
stackoverflow.com/questions/13274625/how-to-set-custom-jsonserializersettings-for-json-net-in-mvc-4-web-api
Any ideas?

Comment: Well the question you in the link refers to AspNet WebApi and MVC4 but you are using working with an MVC3 project right? I believe MVC3 Controllers use the JsonDataContractsSerializer and it may be intercepting you somewhere in the request pipeline. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I think you need to use one of the approaches described in this thread to fix the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109967/using-json-net-as-the-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc-3-is-it-possible

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Yes, I'm using MVC3, but my code is in a razor view, and I'm using a string to assign json generated object to a javascript variable with only a Html.Raw(json) sentence. Anyway, I'll test this case, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your tips
Finally, I've just fix it:
I was working with EntityObject generator, so, my data was not in POCO models. But, if I change to DbContext generator, Json.Net haven't any problems serializing to JSON my new POCO objects.

Anyway, perhaps, any of you could tell me if I missed any code to work with 'EntityObject style'. I'll try your suggestions, it's a matter of pride now... ;)

My Json.Net code remains untouched between EO and DbC versions:
In DataView.cshtml, only this two lines:

```
 JsonSerializerSettings config = new JsonSerializerSettings { MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore, ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, ContractResolver = new ExcludeEntityKeyContractResolver() };
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, Formatting.Indented, config);
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Regards.

Tistklehoff.