# Set NullValueHandling at a controller level

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, asp.net-core

For the moment part, i would like to exclude null values from my api response, so in my startup.cs file, i have this.

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        // Setup json serializer
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

But is it possible to state that on 1 or more controllers, i actually want to include NULL values??

Answer (score 5):

One option is to create custom Json result type, as described in this question: [Using JSON.NET as the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET MVC 3 - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109967/using-json-net-as-the-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc-3-is-it-possible). Then you can have bool var on base controller and use it do disable null's when using custom  `Json` result or even pass option directly:

```
return Json(data, ignoreNulls: true);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get `JsonOutputFormatter` from the `BindingContext.OutputFormatters` inside of the code of your controller. It allows you *dynamically* change the `SerializerSettings`.

Try to include `using Newtonsoft.Json;` in the controller code and to do the following inside of your controller action:

```cs
var f = BindingContext.OutputFormatters.FirstOrDefault(
            formatter => formatter.GetType() ==
                         typeof (Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter))
        as Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter;
if (f != null) {
    //f.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    f.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
}
```

I included `Formatting = Formatting.Indented` just for my tests only, because one see the results immediately. You don't need it of cause.

**UPDATED:** I created the demo project using MVC Web Application with no Authentication. Then I added in `HomeController` the following metod

```cs
public object TestMethod()
{
    var testResult = new {
                         name = "Test",
                         value = 123,
                         nullableProperty = (string) null
                     };

    return testResult;
}
```

and changed the Launch URL of the project to `Home/TestMethod` and started the demo. I could see

```json
{"name":"Test","value":123,"nullableProperty":null}
```

You don't need to add any additional using statements to use the code which I posted initially (one need just have the standard `using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;` and `using System.Linq;`), but the code could be more readable if you would have `using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters;` and `using Newtonsoft.Json;`. I added the using statements for `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters` and `Newtonsoft.Json` and modified the code to the following

```cs
public object TestMethod()
{
    var testResult = new {
                         name = "Test",
                         value = 123,
                         nullableProperty = (string) null
                     };

    var f = BindingContext.OutputFormatters.FirstOrDefault(
                formatter => formatter.GetType() == typeof (JsonOutputFormatter)) as JsonOutputFormatter;
    if (f != null) {
        f.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        f.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    }
    return testResult;
}
```

The output results looks now as following

```json
{
  "name": "Test",
  "value": 123
}
```

The standard code use `"Newtonsoft.Json"` in version 6.0.6. We can add `"Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.2"` in dependencies to use the latest version of `Newtonsoft.Json`. See the problem with resolving of indirect dependencies which I reported in [the issue](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3113) and which is still opened.

You can download the test project from [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/BindingContextTest.zip).

Comment: I cannot seem to see BindingContext from within my controller method?  it this for ASPNET5?

Comment: @user2736022: Yes of cause. Inside of every controller action you have `this` with properties `HttpContext`, `BindingContext` and so on. You can just type `this.` inside of your method. After typing `.` intellysense will show you all properties of `this` including `BindingContext`. C# allows (recommends) you to write `BindingContext` instead of `this.BindingContext`.

Comment: Can you check with namespace it is within?  It says its my controller does not contain a definition for BindingContext

Comment: @user2736022: `BindingContext` is the property of `Controller`. Every MVC6 Controller should be class which e `using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;`. I described all steps in **UPDATED** part of my answer and uploaded [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/BindingContextTest.zip) the test Visual Studio 2015 project, which demonstrates the code.

Comment: MVC Core reuses the same instance of JsonOutputFormatter across all controllers. Changing the serializer setting inside of a controller is nearly identical to modifying it at startup.

Comment: @Pranav: I think so too. Thus one should set the *variable* settings in *all* controllers. One can define derived class from `Controller` class and use it in all controllers. I want to show the way how one can change the `SerializerSettings` **dynamically**. All other code should be written corresponds to exact requirements.

Comment: I am using rc2, this doesnt seem to exist?  rc1 has BindingContext but not rc2...

Comment: @user2736022: You can save a lot of time if you provides correct information initially. RC2 is now in renaming process. A lot of packages, methods, internal structures are renamed. I personally don't want to use it now till the changes will be finished. I tried preliminary version of RC2 before, but now I don't have any working MVC Core project which can be even compiled. So I can't help you with BindingContext.

Comment: @user2736022: I can't compile any code which use preliminary RC2, but it seems that one can get `OutputFormatters` from `HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>().Value.OutputFormatters` instead of `BindingContext` before. Thus `var f = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>().Value.OutputFormatters.OfType<JsonOutputFormatter>().Single();` could work.

Comment: This does not work.  if you change your example, to have 2 methods, the first includes null/spacing, then second excludes it.  Access the first method, its ok, access the second, its ok.  Go back to the first and the settings have been overwritten

Comment: @user2736022: Yes of cause. You should read previous comments too. You questions was **how to access to `SerializerSettings` to be able to change there**. I've shown you how the access the settings and to change there dynamically. MVC hold **one instance** of the settings, thus you should set (reset) the properties in every your controller/controller action.