# Controller returns the type name of the list object instead of contents in the list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the simple code through which i am trying to return list object from a controllers method and display it on browser. Instead browser displays the type of list as:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Below is my code:

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using MvcApplication2.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class CodesController : Controller
    {
        WebClient myclient = new WebClient();

        public IEnumerable<Codes> Get()
        {
            string data = myclient.DownloadString("URL");
            List<Codes> myobj = (List<Codes>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, typeof(List<Codes>));
            return myobj;
        }
    }
}
```

DataModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class Codes
    {
        public string hr { get; set; }
        public string ps { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please let me know where am missing, I want those codes in the testlist to be displayed on the browser instead of the type `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ``. I am very new to MVC, Is it possible to return simple list and render it on browser from the controller instead of using a view.

Comment: You ned to show us the code you have on the View, I think it comes from that

Comment: You may be confusing ApiController with Controller, but I'm not sure. Can you explain the bigger picture of what you wish to accomplish?

Comment: @Massanu thank you for the response, I did not add any view. I am trying to return this list from controller. IS it possible to return from controller.

Comment: @Danny I am trying to display a simple list as shown in my controller.

Comment: You can do it using WebAPI but I'm not sure it is possible to do it using an MVC controller.

Comment: @DannyEllisJr. I already tried it webapi the return result is same as type and not the contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controller actions does not intended to return POCO objects. You would better return instance of a class, inherited from [`ActionResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx), which is responsible to represent your actual result in HTML in desired way.

For example, if you want to execute some view and render HTML, you would use [`Controller.View`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx) method, which return [`ViewResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult(v=vs.118).aspx).

It is not clear how you would like to represent your collection, but I guess it could be JSON. In this case you can use default [`Controller.Json`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.118).aspx) method, or return [some custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109967/using-json-net-as-the-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc-3-is-it-possible) implementation of `ActionResult`.

If you return something not inherited from `ActionResult`, asp.net mvc will try to convert it to `string` and return converted string as plain text without any modification. This method of [`ControllerActionInvoker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controlleractioninvoker(v=vs.118).aspx) class responsible for handling what you return in your actions. Further code will work only with `ActionResult` inheritors so if you return not one of them, it will be converted:

```
/// <summary>Creates the action result.</summary>
/// <returns>The action result object.</returns>
/// <param name="controllerContext">The controller context.</param>
/// <param name="actionDescriptor">The action descriptor.</param>
/// <param name="actionReturnValue">The action return value.</param>
protected virtual ActionResult CreateActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, object actionReturnValue)
{
  if (actionReturnValue == null)
    return new EmptyResult();
  var actionResult = actionReturnValue as ActionResult;
  if (actionResult == null)
  {
    actionResult = new ContentResult()
    {
      Content = Convert.ToString(actionReturnValue, (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    };
  }
  return actionResult;
}
```

Type `List` not overrides `ToString` method, so it's default implementation is to return full type name. In your case it is `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ``.

Try something like this:

```
public class CodesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetListJson()
    {
        var list = new List<string> { "AA", "BB", "CC" };
        return this.Json(list , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult GetListText()
    {
        var list = new List<string> { "AA", "BB", "CC" };
        return this.Content(string.Join(",", list));
    }

    public ActionResult GetListView()
    {
        var list = new List<string> { "AA", "BB", "CC" };
        return this.View(list);
    }
}
```

First method will return *application/json*: `["AA", "BB", "CC"]`

Second method will return *text/plain*: `AA,BB,CC`

Third method will return *text/html*, but you have to create view named `GetListView.cshtml`:

```
@using System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page list</title>
</head>
<body>
    @foreach(var item in this.Model)
    {
        <p>@item</p>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

**Update** according to your comments you want to return just some text. See code below. It will return what you want: `[AA,BB],[AA,BB],[AA,BB]`. Note the result type and the need of manual data serialization.

```
public ActionResult Get()
{
    string data = myclient.DownloadString("URL");
    List<Codes> myobj = (List<Codes>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, typeof(List<Codes>));

    // Let's convert it into what you want.
    var text = string.Join(",", list.Select(x => string.Format("[{0},{1}]", x.hr, x.ps)));
    return this.Content(text);
}
```

Alternately you can create your own `ActionResult`:

```
public class CodesResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly List<Codes> _list;

    public CodesResult(List<Codes> list)
    {
        this._list = list;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        if (this._list != null)
        {
            // You still have to define serialization
            var text = string.Join(",", this._list.Select(x => string.Format("[{0},{1}]", x.hr, x.ps)));
            response.Write(text);
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
public ActionResult Get()
{
    string data = myclient.DownloadString("URL");
    List<Codes> myobj = (List<Codes>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, typeof(List<Codes>));
    return new CodesResult(myobj);
}
```

I don't know what you task is and why you need to return custom plain text. However I would advise you to use [Newtonsoft-based `JsonNetResult` from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109967/using-json-net-as-the-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc-3-is-it-possible). With intendation enabled it will produce pretty readable json. Also it much easy to reuse it for any types of any complexity.

Also, if you need to return data, no any GUI and so on, take a look on [ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api).

Comment: @Iorond I am trying to deserialize a Json string to the list object and display it on browser. I have this JSON string like this: [{"hr":"AA", "PS":"BB"},{"hr":"AA", "PS":"BB"},{"hr":"AA", "PS":"BB"}, {"hr":"AA", "PS":"BB"}] and I deserialized this above string using Jsonconvert.deserialize method into the list and want that list to be displayed as shown : [AA,BB],[AA,BB],[AA,BB].

Comment: @SwethaD You deserialize it into what type? How you want  it to return to browser? As html, json, plain text? Or somehow else? You would better show complete code.

Comment: @Iorond  I deserialized into list object, I want to return it as plain text like this: [AA,BB],[AA,BB],[AA,BB]..

Comment: @loronod I added the code in my question was too big to add in comment, thank you so much for your response...

Comment: @loronod thank you so much for following up, but I still see the type of list and not the contents of the list, when i tried this options:     public ActionResult GetListText()
        {
            var list = new List<string> { "AA", "BB", "CC" };
            return this.Content(string.Join(",", list));
        }

Comment: @loronod when i used this option : var text = string.Join(",", this._list.Select(x => string.Format("[{0},{1}]", x.hr, x.ps)));
            response.Write(text); I get an error saying there is an ambiguity in join method call, not sure why the controller is not returning the data in this format...