# error in webapi - cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings'

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

in webapi jsonrequestbehaviour is not working , showing cannot convert 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings'

code

```
 public ActionResult AddTemprature(string EmployeeName, int EmployeeId, string Location)
        {
            try
            {

                using (EmployeeDBEntities DB = new EmployeeDBEntities())
                {

                    WebApi.Employee emp = new WebApi.Employee();
                    // EmployeeModel Emp = new EmployeeModel();
                    emp.EmpName = EmployeeName;
                    emp.EmpId = EmployeeId;
                    emp.EmpLocation = Location;
                    DB.Employees.Add(emp);
                    DB.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {

            }
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Please hover over 'Json' and tell us where it says it's coming from.  I suspect that there is some funny-ness, like a duplication of `Json` when it should be looking to the controller for it's Json method

Comment: enum system.System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehaviour.may be it should be something like  this "  return Json((object)new { success = false });"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JSON.NET as the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET MVC 3 - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109967/using-json-net-as-the-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc-3-is-it-possible)

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't cause a compile error to put a bool in there.  As long a `Json` is the pure ASP.NET MVC version of Json.  Have you found out where `Json` is defined??  There must be a reason why your `Json` method accepts `JsonSerializerSettings` and not the normal `JsonRequestBehaviour`

Comment: can you select Json and go to definition, is the definition 
`protected internal JsonResult Json(object data, JsonRequestBehavior behavior);`

Comment: protected internal JsonResult<T> Json<T>(T content);

Answer (score 5):

You are using controller json respose, instead of ApiController response type.
Use below code and you should be all set.

```
return new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = false,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Change public class shahriarController : ApiController to
public class shahriarController : Controller.
You have to inherit from Controller, not from ApiController.
It will solve the 'JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet'.

```
public class shahriarController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        List<Student> list = new List<Student>();
        list.Add(new Student() { Name = "sjass", Roll = "5544" });
        list.Add(new Student() { Name = "wwww", Roll = "0777" });
        list.Add(new Student() { Name = "rrttt", Roll = "4355" });

        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Its turned out I had the class defined like " public class PersonalApiController : ApiController" instead of " public class PersonalApiController : Controller".  Changing that resolved the problem.