# json.net saving read only property

Tags: json.net

I just started using json.net in my project.
It worked right out of the box and I didn't read a lot in the documentation.
I want to ask a question someone else asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700053/json-net-read-only-properties-support-for-ignoredatamember).
Is it per default that json.net serializes a read only property?

I have a property in my class that only has a get but json.net serializes it and tries to set it when it deserializes with the result that i get an error. I have to exclude the property with the attribute [JsonIgnore] while I didn't have to use any other attributes to serialize my classes, as I said it worked out of the box.

Regards,
Alexander